# Google Drive Java API error 400 (bad request) when list files in app folder with query

Tags: google-drive-api

There is a Google Drive Java API bug (server side).

```
Files.List listRequest = drive.files().list();
listRequest.setQ("'appfolder' in parents and (title = 'data2010-01.xml' or title='data2010-02.xml' or title = 'data2010-03.xml' or title = 'data2011-04.xml' or title = 'data2011-05.xml' or title = 'data2011-06.xml' or title = 'data2012-07.xml' or title = 'data2012-08.xml' or title = 'data2012-09.xml' or title = 'data2012-10.xml')");
```

Everytime I use the above code I got error response 400 (bad request).
When query is shorter (less conditions) or without clause ('appfolder' in parents) it works fine.

I've got serious problem with my application (which use app folder) since several days because of that error.
Could you please tell me when the error will be fixed?

Comment: Please check if you are able to get the result in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it) with the same query included in the request. Check if you still receive the same error.

Comment: Yes, I still receive the same error when request by API explorer for OAuth 2.0 Scope ".../drive.appdata". 500 - Internal Server Error or 400 - Bad request.